# Rand() not generating random variables in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

I've been trying to apply all advices found in this site but none seems to be working.

For the first part of the code I need to fill an array with random numbers (0 or 1) to simulate an epidemic spreading, but the array obtained is not the desired one at all... this is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N, BC, t, T, i, v[N];
    float b, g, p, r;

    /*Variable values initialization*/
    printf("Enter infection probability:\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);

    printf("Enter the number of individuals:\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    printf("Enter the number of time steps:\n");
    scanf("%d", &T);

    printf("Periodic boundary contitions? (Y:1 / N:0)\n");
    scanf("%d", &BC);   


    /*First set of individuals*/
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){ 
    v[i] = (rand()/RAND_MAX);
    }

    /*Check if array properly initialized*/
    printf("Initial array:\n" );
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("%d-", v[i]);
    }
```

The outcome I expected for the array was something like: 1-0-1-1-0-0-0-..., but I always get the following one:

Initial array:
0-0-2-15-0-0-0-0-0-0-

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a million!

Comment: When you use the variable `N` to define the array `v`, what is the value of `N`? Definitions aren't "remade" retroactively when you initialize `N`. In short you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: apart from that, `rand()/RAND_MAX` only gives `1` if `rand()` happens to return exactly `RAND_MAX`. Probably **not** what you want.

Comment: Your compiler should definitively have warned you about this. Try to increase the warning level. E.g with gcc this would be `-Wall`.

Comment: Also v[N] is an array of ints and you assign rand()/RAND_MAX which is most of the time 0 as you divide int's. Only when rand() produces RAND_MAX you will get one - which is basically never.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `v[N]` after

```
printf("Enter the number of individuals:\n");
scanf("%d", &N);
```

otherwise its size will be random since `N` isn't initialized when the memory allocated for `v[]` based on `N` is set.

If you want just `0` or `1` you should use a modulo:

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){ 
    v[i] = (rand() % 2);
}
```

all the even values generated by `rand` will become `0` and all the odd values will become `1`

Comment: Not that likely nowadays, but some PRNG implementations of `rand()` weren't very random for the least significant bit, so it might be better to shift first.

Comment: "*its size will be random*" <- indeterminate .... "random" would imply some reliable distribution that isn't there.

Comment: To e.g. always use bit 1, you could write `v[i] = !!(rand() & 2);`